# What’s the translation of the following:

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

Magno Gaudio Christiani Doctrinas Christi audimus.

Is it: We, the Christians, hear the teachings of Christ with great joy.

Or the audimus is an error?

Comment: What would make you think that *audimus* is an error?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's an accurate translation.

I presume that your source of confusion is the fact that there seem to be two subjects: (1) an implied first-person plural "we" from *audimus*, and (2) *Christiani*, which would seem to require a **third**-person plural verb.

The trick here is to realize that a noun can be placed in apposition with an (understood or explicit) pronoun.

Here is a famous example from Cicero's First Cataline Oration that uses an explicit pronoun with a noun in apposition:

> **Nos autem fortes viri** satis facere rei publicae **videmur**, si istius furorem ac tela vitamus.

Translation:

> But **we, brave men** [that we are], **seem** to do enough for the republic if we avoid his wrath and weapons.

The same thing is happening in your quote, except that the *nos* is implied. My only suggestion, for idiomatic English, would be to say, "We Christians" instead of "We, the Christians."

Comment: Or, of course, the famous *Nos Póloni non cúramus quantítatem syllábarum* ;-)